# How to set background color of an image using draw2d?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I have drawn one rectangle by using `RectangleFigure` in **draw2d**. And I am able to
color the rectangle figure by calling `rectangleFigure.setBackgroundColor`.
Now the same way I want to color the *Image* also. For that I used `ImageFigure` in 
**draw2d** and I gave the background color by calling `ImageFigure.setBackgroundColor()`.
But it does not give any color for me. So How can I give the background color
to the image figure in draw2d?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RectangleFigure extends Shape which draws it's own background by default. ImageFigure directly extends Figure which will only draw the background if you set it as Opaque:

```
imageFigure.setOpaque(true);
```